# Compare data in 2 tables held in 2 different databases

Tags: oracle, postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-reconciliation

I have an oracle db and a postgresql db. Both have a set of tables which have exactly the same definition. I want to compare the data in both these tables on an on-going basis. Are there any AWS services or open source tools available to do this comparison?

Answer (score 1):

From PostgreSQL this is a relatively easy task with [Oracle FDW](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) which will permit you to map the Oracle Table into PostgreSQL and query it directly from SQL as if it was on the cluster you're connected to.